# LibreOffice Calc: Count number of empty cells only if preceeding cell is non-empty

Tags: libreoffice, countif, libreoffice-calc

Having column A and column B, I need to count the number of empty cells in a given range in column B if the preceding cell in column A has content (specifically a date, if it matters). If this is possible, how would this happen?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, and shorter but *better?*:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"",A:A,"<>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this `=COUNTBLANK( B2:B34 ) - COUNTBLANK( A2:A34 )`
Is there a better way to do this?